# Display multiple canvas elements above each other

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have 2 canvas elements, both have exact the same size and position. The first one should be my background, and the other one is for the scenes. When I run my code, it shows only the canvas which is first loaded in my HTML.

```
<canvas id='arena'></canvas>
<canvas id='actions'></canvas>
```

So how can I make the background visible and the scenes transparent?

Comment: Please show your CSS as well, or convert this to a code snippet that demonstrates the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I can give you an link: http://manuel03.bplaced.net/game/game.html  I dont use much css, only width and height 100%. Pure js and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to position the canvas elements.

```
canvas {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped me a lot